# Consider the binomial expansion to answer two questions.

Tags: calculus

[image]

I don't understand this question at all. I know how to use binomial expansion and finding the term using $T_{r+1} = {n \choose r} \cdot P^{n-r} \cdot q^r$ or just simply expanding the equation to find the term.

Comment: Just expand and compare.

Comment: Do you understand part (i)?

Comment: @Lai I'm slightly confused about why you used 100 there. Could you help explain that to me? Also, assuming that the 100s are 1000s, what would you mean by compare both sides

Comment: Sorry for my typos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(i) $$(x+2)^{1000}=\sum_{n=0}^{1000}\left(\begin{array}{c}1000 \\ n\end{array}\right) 2^{1000-n} \cdot x^n$$

Comparing both sides, we have
$$
a_n=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1000 \\
n
\end{array}\right) 2^{1000-n}
$$
(ii)
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} & =\frac{\left(\begin{array}{c}
1000 \\
n
\end{array}\right) 2^{1000-n}}{\left(\begin{array}{c}
1000\\
n-1
\end{array}\right)  2^{1001-n}} \\
& =\frac{(n-1) !(1001-n)!}{2 n !(1000-n) !} \\
& =\frac{1001-n}{2 n} \\
\frac{a_{n }}{a_{n-1}}>1 & \Leftrightarrow \frac{1001-n}{2 n !}>1 \\
& \Leftrightarrow n<\frac{1001}{3} \\
& \Leftrightarrow n \leqslant 333
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore the greatest coefficient is
$$
\begin{aligned}
a_{333} & =\left(\begin{array}{c}
1000 \\
333
\end{array}\right) 2^{1000-333} =\left(\begin{array}{c}
1000 \\
333
\end{array}\right) 2^{667}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: what does the 2(2)^1000-n mean? Also what does that bracketing mean?

Comment: I'm also not understanding how a(n) = (1000-1Cn-1) * 2^1001 - n

Comment: I don't know if they are typos, but some things just don't make sense. The next part isn't the same as the previous

Comment: Another comment sorry, but shouldn't (1001 - n) be (1001 - n)! ?

Comment: Sorry for having such typos. Fixed.

Comment: I'm confused about this question. How you can deduce the formula for $a_n$ while $n=1000$? As a matter of fact, $a_{1000} = 1$.

Comment: You are confused. $a_n$ are the coefficients of x^n in the expansion of $(x+2)^{1000}$.  So we never fix $n=1000$.  $a_{1000}$ is only one of the coefficients. For example, $(x+2)^3=1x^3+6x^2+12x+8. a_1=1, a_2=6, a_3=12$ and $a_4=8$.  The maximum coefficient is 12, which can be found by the ratio of two adjacent coefficients such as $\frac{a_2}{a_1}=6>1,  \frac{a_3}{a_2}=2>1 $from which we know that $a_n$ is increasing until $\frac{a_4}{a_3}= \frac{8}{12}<1$. So we can conclude that $a_3$ is the greatest coefficient.